# Slack iOS URL Scheme

Tags: ios, slack-api

Can I link directly to message someone on my Slack team from my iOS app? If I just open a `slack:` url, it will open the slack app, but not linking to someone's message thread. I tried a few obvious ones:

- `slack:ptarjan`
- `slack://ptarjan`

but I'm punching in the dark.

For reference, Facebook Messenger's is `fb-messenger://user-thread/{user-id}` and skype's is `skype:{user-id}?chat'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard from them, it is not supported yet but planned.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party here, but currently this works with the desktop app:

`slack://channel?id=<channel/group/user-id>&team=<team-id>`

Use the Slack API to get your team id with [`team.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.info) and your channel ids with [`channel.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list).

I don't know if this works their native apps or in-browser app. It's worth noting that it's not official so Slack could potentially change it at their whim and without notice.